# $f$ be holomorphic and non-zero. Prove that $\exists r>0$ such that $f(z)\ne0\forall |z|=r$

Tags: complex-analysis

I know that if the set $A=\{z|\ f(z)=0\}$ has a limit point (i.e. $A^d\ne\emptyset$), then $f=0$ on whole $\Bbb{C}$.

So, from this we can say for all $r>0$ there is $|z|=r$ such that $f(z)\ne0$.

I have to find $r>0$ such that $f$ is non zero for all $|z|=r$.

Let us assume on contrary that for all $r>0$, there is $z_r$ such that $f(z_r)=0$.

To show $A$ has a limit point. It's enough to proof $\{z_r|\ r>0\}$ has a limit point in $\Bbb{C}$.

But I'm not able to proof this set has a limit point. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The circles $|z|=r$ are disjoint. Suppose $f(z_r)=0$ with $|z_r|=r$. Then $\{z_r: r >0\}$ is an uncountable. set. Hence there exists a positive integer $n$ such that the are infinitely many points of this set in $\{z: |z| \leq n\}$. [To see this use proof by contradiction]. But any infinite subset of $\{z: |z| \leq n\}$ has a limit point and this makes $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: Thanks sir. I realised just now that the set $B=\{z_r|\ r>0\}$ is separable hence lindeloff. And if $B$ doesn't have any limit point then $B$ is discrete hence singleton sets are open cover of $B$ but it does does not have any countable subcover. As $B$ is uncountable.